# iptables has port 80 open but nmap shows it closed

Tags: debian, web-server, iptables, port, nmap

I'm having some troubles getting a Debian webserver to open up port 80 for HTTP traffic. In my iptables, I opened up port 80 using the following commands:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Running an iptables -L then showed the following rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:www
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:www

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

However, after all of this, I ran nmap -sS 127.0.0.1 and discovered that port 80 *still* isn't open. Here are the results:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000080s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

How is it possible for rules to be in place to open a port in iptables but still have that same port closed in Nmap? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your web server running? Can you post the output of `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`?

Comment: Sure thing!
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: The `connection refused` error means there is no process listening on the port. Can you post the output of `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 80`?

Comment: tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      30191/apache2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output of `netstat -lnp | grep 80`, it seems that your apache server is listening on the port 8080 not the default one 80.

Also, the line:

```
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

from nmap output confirms this fact.

In summary, the port 80 is not open in your machine as apache is listening on 8080 instead.

Comment: Ahhhh, right you are! It turns out that nmap shows the ports being listened on, *not* the ports that are currently open. When I switched to port 80 in my apache ports.conf and sites.enabled files, nmap now shows port 80 open. Thank you!