# Site works on one port but not another

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, port

I'm writing a website that I'm having some trouble getting online with a Debian server using Apache2. When I run the site on port 8080 (i.e. www.example.com:8080), the whole thing runs fine and the page is loaded. However, when I tell Apache to use port 80 instead, it doesn't work. When I visit it (i.e. www.example.com), it just seems to load endlessly.

I made sure that port 8080 was changed to port 80 in both /etc/apache2/ports.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysitesfile. I also made sure to restart the apache server after doing this: afterwards, Nmap showed Apache listening on port 80.

I determined [earlier](https://serverfault.com/questions/343803/iptables-has-port-80-open-but-nmap-shows-it-closed) that both port 80 and port 8080 were indeed open on the server. So what gives? So long as both port 80 and port 8080 are open, what could be causing a problem where it works on one but not the other? Were there files that needed to be edited that I didn't edit?

Any help would be VERY much appreciated!

Comment: can you confirm three-way traffic with: tcpdump -i INSERTINTERFACENAMEHERE port 80? Also, is HostnameLookups Off in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: The result of the tcpdump command was: `tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes`. Was that what you were looking for?
Also, /etc/apache2/httpd.conf appears to be completely empty.

Comment: Okay, I forgot, this is Debian. Look at apache2.conf.

However, assuming that you are listening on the port that your IP is attached, this suggest that traffic is not evening coming through in the begin. Can you run that in another window and then do a nc -z localhost 80?

Comment: You may want to consider testing something that's not port 80.  @chakram88's answer is probably the most likely to be right given what we know, but trying to connect on port 81, 82, etc., might give you more information as to rather the problem lies on your server, network, or ISP.

Comment: Troubleshoot. Does `netstat` show Apache listening on port 80? What IP is it bound to? Can you `telnet` to port 80 from the local machine? From a remote machine?

Comment: @Rilindo HostnameLookups is indeed off. Running `nc -z localhost 80` with the tcpdump didn't result in any output from tcpdump.
@Redmumba I took your suggestion and tried both ports 81 and 82 - neither of them worked. However, when I tried a completely random port (9979), it worked perfectly.
@DavidSchwartz The only mention I see of port 80 in `netstat` is `tcp6       0   0 :::80   :::*   LISTEN` - which doesn't mention Apache. I'm able to telnet to port 80 from the local machine, but not a remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the server located?

If you are running this server at home, your ISP may be blocking port 80.

Comment: Nope, the server is running at school (a .edu domain). Is there any way to check from a remote computer whether the port is blocked by some intermediary?

Comment: Yeah. Can you connect to the site within the same network on port 80, then try again from a system outside your router/firewall. If it works inside the same subnet but not outside, then something between is blocking it.

Comment: Or, since it's a .edu (college?) you contact their IT department and ask if they're blocking the port. Is this running from a dorm? If so, then it's absolutely no surprise they'd block it. Students abusing network access is a huge problem for EDU's...

Comment: You can work out where it's firewalled with tcptraceroute (tracing on port 80)

Comment: The preferred method is to `telnet <hostname> 80`, which will open up a raw connection to the port--this doesn't rely on an existing service being setup.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Unfortunately, I have no other computer inside the network that I have root privileges for, and none of the other computers have telnet installed =/. The server isn't being run from within the dorms (I know they'd frown upon that!) - it's inside the CSE department. @tumbleweed From the looks of `tcptraceroute`, the packet is making it there - the final line of output is `2  myserver.cse.school.edu (12.3.45.6) [open]  0.196 ms  0.091 ms  0.101 ms` - very frustrating!

Comment: You don't need root privileges to open a web browser and bring up a standard web page...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Ahhh, great point! I've become a little too fixated on those command line tools... and you're absolutely right! It works like a charm within the network, but outside it's no good. I'll try and email the sysadmins and see if they know what's blocking it. Thanks!