# Apache2 not working with port 80 but working on port 8000 in Proxmox (same configuration)

Tags: port-forwarding, apache2, proxmox, nmap, port-80

Some months ago I hired a Kimsufi server, I tried to forward ports without luck.

I abandon the server, some days ago I started to reconfigure everything again, but I'm having still problems.

I discovered that some ports are blocked by default, but I still don't have a clue how to unblock them.

The main problem is that I installed apache2 on a virtual machine (with Debian), if I use port 8000 to host the web eveything works well (using http://z3nth10n.net:8000).

This is my interfaces configuration (`/etc/network/interfaces`):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp4s0 inet manual

iface enp5s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  <public ip>
        netmask  24
        gateway  <public gateway>
        bridge-ports enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  192.168.5.99
        netmask  24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.xx.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.xx.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.xx.55:8000
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.xx.55:8000
        post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.xx.55:80
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.xx.55:80
        post-up iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.xx.55 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
        post-down iptables -D FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.xx.55 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I added these two lines:

```
        post-up iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.xx.55 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
        post-down iptables -D FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.xx.55 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

But this still not working.

nmap shows that the port is open on the virtual machine, but closed on the host machine, so this is confusing me.

I read ([iptables has port 80 open but nmap shows it closed](https://serverfault.com/questions/343803/iptables-has-port-80-open-but-nmap-shows-it-closed)) that if the port isn't on use it will not be shown as open on nmap.

Also I executed the `netstat -lnp | grep 80` command, and this is the output:

**HOST MACHINE**

```
root@ns324919:~# netstat -lnp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8006            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1572/pveproxy worke
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17217    980/qmeventd         /var/run/qmeventd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2380     1/init               /run/rpcbind.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18056    991/watchdog-mux     /run/watchdog-mux.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34980709 1975/kvm             /var/run/qemu-server/100.vnc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23800    1665/master          private/bsmtp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23803    1665/master          private/scalemail-backend
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     23806    1665/master          private/mailman
```

**VIRTUAL MACHINE**

```
root@debian:~# netstat -lnp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      808/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      14825/apache2       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12719    808/mysqld           /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

So, I can assume that the port is not in use on the host machine.

Also, I disabled the firewall:

```
root@ns324919:~# pve-firewall status
Status: disabled/stopped
```

I disabled everything to make sure it was not interfering with my test, but I have doubts because of Idk if I created a DMZ network or I need to forward something by using the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

check the httpd.conf/apache.conf file, the `Listen` port should be 80 rather than 8000.

Is this a cloud instance? if yes, even though you allow it with `iptables` it is not exposed to the world. You will need to open the port in your provider's ACL.

Comment: It's listening on the port 80. You can check it ![here](https://i.gyazo.com/b96cb926fbface1e20fc14e282335a0d.png) and ![here](https://i.gyazo.com/708bf0306fb8d1aa59370518f14dbcb5.png). (I'm using the default config)... I'm using a dedicated server on Kimsufi, what is an ACL?

Comment: if it is listensing on port 80, try running `curl localhost -I`, this should return a response for 200. An ACL (access control list) defines what ports are opened in your cloud provided for your server and who can access those ports.

Comment: `curl localhost -I` displays a 200 response. I will research for that term. Thanks!

Comment: It means your server is listening on port 80 and you need to allow 80 to public access.

Comment: I don't find anything related to ACL on my Kimsufi panel, can you help me to search? Thanks!